# Recursive - stack overflow error

Tags: c#, recursion, divide-and-conquer

Given an unsorted array find the max and min values. I'm trying to do this in a recursive, divide and conquer way but I keep getting a stack overflow error. I debugged and i keep getting the error in my recursive calls but do not know what is wrong or how to fix it.

I do have static min and max variables.

Thanks for the information and help!

```
static void findMaxMin(int[] array, int start, int end)
{
    if (end == 2)
    {
        setMaxMin(array);
    }
    else
    {
        int mid = ((end) / 2);
        findMaxMin(array, start, mid);
        findMaxMin(array, mid + 1, end);
    }
}
private static void setMaxMin(int[] array)
{
    if (array[0] > array[1])
    {
        max = array[0];
        min = array[1];
    }
    else
    {
        min = array[0];
        max = array[1];
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems you have missing the exit point, you need to tell when the code should stop.  For example start >= end.

Comment: I suspect in your base condition of recursion.

Comment: Well `setMaxMin` only ever looks at the first two indexes, so exactly how will that work if the array is longer,

Comment: Use a queue to remove recursion.

Comment: Why are you using recursion for this anyway? It's a simple matter of looping through the array and comparing current value with the previous one. Recursion is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one simple way to do it (without recursion):

```
void FindMinAndMaxValues(int[] array out int min, out int max)
{
    min = int.MaxValue,
    max = int.MinValue;

    foreach(var val in array)
    {
        max = (val > max) ? val : max;
        min = (val < min) ? val : min;
    }
}
```

Please note that I'm using out parameters here. This is done for simplicity of the code. Usually, I would prefer to either return a designated class or a [tuple](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536(v=vs.110).aspx).

Also, LINQ has [min](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.min(v=vs.110).aspx) and [max](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.max(v=vs.110).aspx) extension methods that you can use - so the entire thing turns to something like this:

```
var max = array.Max();
var min = array.Min();
```